# Getting Requester Info In WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working on a service that will support mobile applications on the Android, BlackBerry, iOS, and WP7 platforms. These applications will connect to various REST-based WCF services that I am working on. I would like to see what information a client application passes to my service. In an effort to do this, I've written the current operation in my WCF service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetRequesterInfo")]
public string GetRequesterInfo()
{
  OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;

  string message = "Session ID: " + context.SessionId;
  return message;
}
```

When I call this code, I notice that the `SessionId` is an empty string. In addition, I would like to get as much information about the client as possible. For instance, if this were ASP.NET, I could use the `HttpRequest` object and get:

- HttpMethod
- IsLocal
- IsSecureConnection
- RequestType
- Url.AbsoluteUri
- Url.OriginalString
- UserAgent
- UserHostAddress
- UserHostName
- Browser.Id
- Browser.Browser
- Browser.CanInitiateVoiceCall
- Browser.ClrVersion.Minor
- Browser.Cookies
- Browser.EcmaScriptVersion
- Browser.GatewayVersion
- Browser.InputType
- Browser.MobileDeviceManufacturer
- Browser.MobileDeviceModel

While there are more properties, I'm sure you get the idea. This leads me to several questions:

1. How do I get the request thread associated with the request to my WCF service? I thought that's what OperationContext was for. But I'm open to correction.
2. How do I get all of the property name / values associated with a request to a WCF service?
3. Am I asking for something that makes sense or am I off my rocker? It seems like I should be able to get some info about the requesting client.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageProperties` :

```
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;

if (context != null)
{
    MessageProperties messageProperties = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
```

If the request actually came from a browser, you can get a `HttpRequest` object, which is what you asked for.

Here's a screen capture of my `MessageProperties`, it should give you enough information on how to access these properties:

[image]

Comment: I am not able to programmatically access the MessageProperties `values. messageProperties.Values[2]` raises this error:
`Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<object>'`.

Comment: @ADC, Try accessing it's Keys collection, first. See above in the picture, what's enumerated isn't the values, it's the AllKeys.