# Get IP details for accessing webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have create a web service using wcf and publish in public. Now i want to get the system IP details of who is trying to access my services. I don't know whether its possible or not. If its possible means tell me that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Requester Info In WCF Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605170/getting-requester-info-in-wcf-service)

Answer (score 1):

Simple!

```
string ip = String.Empty;
var props = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties;
var endpointProperty = props[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
if (endpointProperty != null)
 {
      ip = endpointProperty.Address;
 }
```

**NOTE** It will work perfect after deployment. On *localhost*, it will give you Network loopback addresses. So, don't worry about that. Moreover! There will be different loopback addresses for IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: @Serv! I forgot that it was loopback. Lol. Thanks!

Comment: That's what the edit function is for. You're welcome

Answer (score 0):

All of the request information is passed along with the request as [server variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). There are a whole bunch with all sorts of different information have a look [at W3Schools list](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp).

In the case of the IP address it is stored in the REMOTE_ADDR variable, you can quickly access this from the Request in a webservice using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Comment: You just duplicated a well answer question

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get IP Address.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```